# Delegate sub domain to parent in Azure DNS

Tags: azure, dns

When I do a DNS lookup on my sub domain I'm getting the following error:

```
Delegation not found at parent.
```

Anybody know how to delegate the sub domain to the parent using Azure portal (and not PowerShell). Read [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-domain-delegation/#delegating-sub-domains-in-azure-dns) article but it does not explain how to do it through the portal.

For example:

Parent: example.com

Sub domain: beta.example.com

Comment: Did you add the NS records in the parent zone in Azure DNS?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that currently this is only supported using PowerShell or invoking an API command. You'll find that before you can do everything in the portal then you will have to break out to PowerShell or the API to perform a number of actions to a variety of tasks in Azure RM.

My recommendation would be to stick with PowerShell, I'm not aware of any timescales for adding this support to the portal.